# What is a valid use case for the javascript `Infinity` value?

Tags: javascript, infinity

I recently saw the `Infinity` Number used to set a max number of listeners for an event emitter in node.

`Infinity` has some interesting behavior associated with it. If multiplied/added/subtracted by any other number its result will be `Infinity`.  This seems like it would cause unexpected/unwanted behavior if ever used.

Why is it even in the spec? [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-infinity) In what case would you ever need to use `Infinity`? What was the purpose of creating it in the language?

In this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452076/what-is-the-infinity-property-used-for-in-javascript) there is a use case that uses it to find a max number from a list of numbers. Although this example works, the `Infinity` value is not needed to accomplish the task. It could be done very easily without it.

Comment: "*Why is it even in the spec?*" - because JavaScript uses standard IEEE 754 floating point numbers, and those have an infinity value.